# docker: mounting fuse directory: Says directory does not exists

Tags: docker-compose, fuse, sshfs

I have a `fuse` directory mounted using sftpman.

```
sftpman setup --id "some_fuse_directory" --host "xx.xxx.x.xx" --user "root" \
--mount_point "/path/on/server/to/see" --auth_method=publickey --ssh_key "/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa"

and then

sftpman mount some_fuse_directory
```

and then i can see the folder `/path/on/server/to/see` at `/mnt/sshfs/some_fuse_directory`

Eg:

```
/mnt/sshfs/some_fuse_directory
```

Now i try to mount this directory into my container in docker-compose

```
  webapp:
    image: "python-3.7.9-buster"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: /mnt/sshfs/some_fuse_directory
        target: /root/some_fuse_directory
```

When I try docker-compose up it says `/mnt/sshfs/some_fuse_directory` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Use volume in this way;

webapp:

```
image: "python-3.7.9-buster"

volumes:

  **- /mnt/sshfs/some_fuse_directory:/root/some_fuse_directory**
```